# Ubuntu partitioned my HDD and I can't extend it back

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

Earlier this year I decided to try Ubuntu so I installed it as dual boot on my Windows, little did I know back then I could live boot from a USB Stick. I got a 1TB HDD (Windows is on my SSD) and when I installed it, it took 200(ish)GB from it to create an environment from Ubuntu. I deleted Ubuntu a few weeks after and now I can't extend my HDD back to 1TB, Windows reads it as a 680GB HDD that has 244GB Unallocated. When I try to extend my volume back to 1TB I get this error:

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The EFI partition in Disk 1, after the "Local Disk (D:)" is what prevents this partition to be extended.

Knowing that this partition was wrongly created - there's an EFI partition on the drive it's actually booting from and that one is absolutely required - it can be deleted/removed.

Once done you will be able to extend "Local Disk (D:)" partition as much as the remaining unallocated space in that drive.

Comment: It doesn't work to delete the EFI partition. I found some tutorials on the internet about deleting it from diskpart but I keep getting errors `DISKPART> SET ID=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7

Virtual Disk Service error:
The operation is not supported by the object.
`

Comment: You can boot any Linux live session - like you did to install Ubuntu -, open GParted and do it from there, including partition resize. Or with any third-party tool. Had you correctly installed Ubuntu before you wouldn't be dealing with this problem now.